# Storing a PFObject pointer in an app's PFConfig

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfobject

I want to store a pointer to a specific object as an Object Pointer in a `PFConfig`, similar to how objects can point to each other in the database. I see there is a way to create an `Object` field in the `PFConfig`, but when I enter the corresponding `objectID` it says "invalid value for Object Type". 
How do I store object links in the `PFConfig`?

Comment: Haven't tried this, so I won't make it an answer yet, but try setting the config value to: `{__type:'Pointer', className:'MyClass',  objectId:'1234xyz'}`

Comment: It gives me the same "invalid value for Object type" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Object` field type in `PFConfig` in looks like it only stores JSON objects (converted to `NSDictionary` with the iOS API), not relations to other Parse objects. And it seems to do some sort of validation, so even if you enter `{"__type":"Pointer", "className":"MyClass", "objectId":"1234xyz"}` (which is valid JSON), the save fails validation with a `__type field is not allowed.` error.

Doesn't look like it can be done with native functionality sorry. You could store your own pointer style object (i.e., just store the object ID, or a `{"type": "pointer", "objectId": "ABC123"}` style reference), but you'd be responsible for managing the relationship, and retrieving the downstream object.

You could also try converting the object you want to save to a JSON representation, but if you wanted to use it as a real `PFObject` you'd need to reconstruct the object based on the data in the `PFConfig`, and it's probably safer just to load a real `PFObject` based on a reference if the ability to update that object is important to your config.

Comment: Good answer.  Its better that it doesn't work, imo.  Saving objectIDs in any format is a brittle dependence on something that ought to be considered internal to the object.  Better to save something that will parameterize a query that will result in the desired object.  This way the desired object can be deleted and re-added without breaking the config.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my suggestion under @rickerbh's excellent answer, consider saving something that *indicates* the desired object, rather than pointing to it.  This way it can be found in a query, even if the object's objectId changes.

For example, you could add a config parameter named `myConfigParam` equal to  `{ "class":"MyClass", "uniqueField":"foo" }`, where one or more uniqueField attributes fully describe the object.  Then, the config'd object can be picked up this way, in objective-c...

```
- (void)fetchConfigObjectWithCompletion:(void (^)(PFObject *, NSError *))completion {
    [PFConfig getConfigInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFConfig *config, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSString *className = config[@"myConfigParam"][@"class"];
            NSString *uniqueField = config[@"myConfigParam"][@"uniqueField"];
            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:className];
            [query whereKey:@"uniqueField" equalTo: uniqueField];
            [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
        } else {
            completion(nil, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Since the config object is rendered as an NSDictionary, you could even iterate its keys, and add equalTo constraints to the query in a loop without knowing on the client what those keys are.

Comment: How can you iterate its keys? I see PFConfig has an internal object _parametersDictionary when i'm in the debugger, but how can I access that in code?